# Custom ASP.NET MVC Route In Nested Folders

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

I want sub-folders in my MVC application, so the current routes just don't cut it.

I've got a folder structure such as

```
Views/Accounts/ClientBalances/MyReport.aspx
```

and I'm wanting a URL such as `http://myapp/Accounts/ClientBalances/MyReport`.  How do you achieve this with mapping routes?  I've had a bash but I'm not very savvy with them.  I thought it'd be along the lines of

```
 routes.MapRoute( _
        "Accounts/ClientBalances", _
        "Accounts/ClientBalances/{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
        New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = ""} _
    )
```

I've had no luck though.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at ASP.NET MVC 2's **[areas](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/what-is-new-in-aspnet-mvc#_TOC3_2)**; they look like very similar to what you're trying to achieve. You can watch a quick, 3-minutes video introducing them [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/aspnet-mvc-2-areas).

If you can't (or don't want to) use them, then check [this answer](http://forums.asp.net/p/1508860/3588122.aspx#3588122) about nested view folders. In summary:

> You can just return the appropriate view like this (from the action method):
>
> ```
> return View("~/Views/controllername/modulename/actionname.ascx", [optional model]);
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The location of the view has nothing to do with the route.
Your views should be in Views/[ControllerName]